# Как с помощью aiogram сделать команду 'Обнять'

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

У меня просьба, мне нужно сделать команду "обнять".
Но я не могу понять как это сделать, не могли бы вы помочь?

Как должна работать команда:

Ответ на сообщение -> Бот пишет текст (юзер человека который написал команду) Обнял (Юзер человека на чье сообщение ответили).

Заранее спасибо! Перерыл весь интернет, но не нашел ничего.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
@dp.message_handler(text='обнять')
    async def send_hugg(message: types.Message):
      if message.reply_to_message:
        await message.answer(f'  | @{message.from_user.username} обнял(-а) @{message.reply_to_message.from_user.username}')
      else:
        pass
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]